# LWC: Maximum Blob Size From JS To APEX

Tags: lightning-web-components, fileupload, limitexception, wire, heapsizelimit

I want to make a "custom file upload" LWC component as I am in need to build a specific design for an upload process.

There are a few things I am not sure about.

1. What  would be the **maximum size** of a blob that I can pass from the JS side to APEX.
2. Is using a `@wire` method to get to APEX the best approach here? If
   not what would be a better way?
3. Is it possible to chunk the blob, pass one chunk at a time and store it in the same `ContentVersion`? Example: I will chunk the file blob depending on the size limit(heap size limit and what I can pass from JS to APEX). Then I want to pass one chunk and save it in a `ContentVersion`. Then pass the next chunk, have APEX pull the `ContentVersion`, append the new blob to what is already in the `ContentVersion` and save. Then keep doing the same thing until all chunks have been passed to SF and appended to each other. Is this going to create a new version every time that I try to save or can I re-save in the same version?

I tried to explain my concerns to the best of my ability. Please if anything doesn't make sense let me know and I will try to elaborate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What would be the maximum size of a blob that I can pass from the JS
>   side to APEX.

It was documented to be 1 mb from lightning component to Apex in 1 transaction. However I do not find that documentation now. Also in my testing it started throwing error after about 716kb

> Is using a @wire method to get to APEX the best approach here? If not
>   what would be a better way?

Imperative apex is better suited for file upload because **To use @wire to call an Apex method, you must set cacheable=true.** and so can only get data

> Is it possible to chunk the blob, pass one chunk at a time and store
>   it in the same ContentVersion? Example: I will chunk the file blob
>   depending on the size limit(heap size limit and what I can pass from
>   JS to APEX). Then I want to pass one chunk and save it in a
>   ContentVersion. Then pass the next chunk, have APEX pull the
>   ContentVersion, append the new blob to what is already in the
>   ContentVersion and save. Then keep doing the same thing until all
>   chunks have been passed to SF and appended to each other. Is this
>   going to create a new version every time that I try to save or can I
>   re-save in the same version?

Using chunking you can upload around 4mb of file in same content version/document. If its more than 4mb, it will throw error and so is better to have check < 4mb of total size.

---

The limitations are enforced by salesforce for custom components (not standard) as stated in [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm):

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How can `<lightning-file-upload>` allow for files up to 2 GB then? It's also using `ContentVersion` and `ContentDocument` right? Is there a way for me to reach that file size?

Comment: added in answer the reason

Comment: The "about 716kb" is because the file must be base64-encoded. This would align with the 1MB limit that you had in mind, so this sounds right.

Comment: @Arthlete The 2GB thing happens because it uses a REST API designed to handle the 2GB limit. If you go through Apex, you're instead limited.

Comment: @sfdcfox. You cannot do callout from component directly?

Comment: @salesforce-sas I believe you can do this if you add your salesforce API domain as a CSP trusted site now.

Comment: @sfdcfox. Probably I may be missing something but when I tried it, it was not working. However, the enabled CSP trusted sites were directly able to interact with URLs in static resource files like pusher notifications

Comment: I might try to do this through the REST API and let you know how it goes.